# How can hide my communication key in flash game?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I will develop a game with server/client pattern. Client and server communicated through TCP socket. And for the server's data security, we encrypted our data stream with some key.

But here's the problem, the actionscript code be easily decompiled with tools. So the key is NOT safe even after obfuscation. You can still restore it if you like to spend more time.

I also checked FlashCC project but it will cost us when combined stage3d.

So is there anyway to hide my key?

Comment: Who are you trying to keep the communication secure from? The user himself or a third party attacker on the network?

Comment: The hacker player can use the key to send fake messages to server to cheat the server logic and gain the profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that you can't have a 100% unbreakable swf. The only thing you can do is to multiply the obstacles to discourage the hacker.

As said in a comment, the safest method would be to have the whole game logic on the server and let the server compute the scores (or other sensitive data) itself. But depending on the type of game, this may be a really stupid idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use asymmetric encryption TLS or SSL over socket. Although flash player 11 has native SecureSocket it has some problems, so I recommend you TLSSocket from [as3cryptolib](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/) ([here](https://github.com/fsbmain/as3public/tree/master/as3crypto_patched) is the fork of the last version of official as3crypto lib with some critical fixes from the [issues](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/issues/list) list)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think the asymmetric encryption won't help here. Because the player still can use the public key to encrypt the data and the server side will accepted it.

Comment: In asymmetric client uses server's public key (from certificate) for data encryption and decryption is able only on the server with it's private key. You can even store the hole certificate on client to invalidate the server, it's secure because private key is stored only in the server.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand the client use public key for encryption. But the problem is if someone breakdown the client program and get the public key, so he knows the way to talk to server. The private key is secure but can not prevent client fake packages using the public key.

Comment: You are right, this is possible. TLS encryption protects from the traffic tampering by the third part more than the client itself. There aren't 100% method to prevent the reverse engineering of the flash client and protocol, obfuscation sometime do more head ache than useful work to developers ) The only way to prevent server hacking from client is to write the thin client (or validate all client messages) with all logic on the server side.